# The network connection was lost error when app move from background to foreground

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am working on a bank app where I have to login in a bank with Two-factor auth.

During the second factor Auth, I have to wait for the user to switch the app & open Bank to authorize the Login access. My app is waiting for service response from Bank.

But when I move the app in background, service call gets fail.

Below is the error

Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost.

How to call the service while app in background mode for few seconds?

Does Cookies make any effect on service call?

Please suggest.

Comment: is your app capability has 'background fetch' enabled?

Comment: yes, i tried but no effect.

Comment: Use `beginBackgroundTask(expirationHandler:)` to keep your app alive in the background for up to 180 seconds